# Push notification payload is without whitespace in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to send a notification to an iOS device using Worklight. My problem is that in the payload I receive from the APNS server, the notification is without white spaces:

Expected Notification

```
"aps" : {
"alert" :
{ "action-loc-key" : "", "body" : "You have a new message." }
,
"badge" : 0,
"sound" : "",
},
"payload" : "
{"alias":"sometext","body":"Uldis:Testingamessage","createdDate":141101237574,"msgId":5412327,"msgType":"WARNING","scheduledDate":141121037574,"sub":"Uldis:Testmessage","type":"MK_MSG","updatedDate":121411037574}
"
}
```

Obtained Notification

```
"aps" : {
"alert" :
{ "action-loc-key" : "", "body" : "You have a new message." }
,
"badge" : 0,
"sound" : "",
},
"payload" : "
{\"alias\":\"sometext\",\"body\":\"Uldis:Testingamessage\",\"createdDate\":1411037574,\"msgId\":5423327,\"msgType\":\"WARNING\",\"scheduledDate\":141123037574,\"sub\":\"Uldis:Testmessage\",\"type\":\"MT_MSG\",\"updatedDate\":141123037574}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. when sending "test message", I get in the device "test message" - with the whitespace. Edit the question and add the following: java version, device type, device OS version, how the push is being sent and processed before worklight sends it out - meaning, your implementation of the push sending.

Comment: this is happening only with the payload, the body of the notification is good

Comment: @IdanAdar Any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: Not at this time. But according to what you're saying the end result is OK? The user sees the message With spaces.

Comment: You are saying that payload is being received without white spaces but the sample you shared above is exactly the same as the inputted payload except formatting (\") . Try to send a different payload message. Start with a small message and then increase its size. Plus provide details as asked by @IdanAdar

Comment: Thats the problem , the \ is supposed to be the white spaces what else detail's you need specify it. There is no prblem in getting the notification and based on the payload value we are displaying it so we need the payload with space but its not. And also any notification you try , does it works with white spaces.

Comment: I am still trying to understand from you the ACTUAL issue. When you receive the notification in the device. What do you see in the UI? The message with spaces, or without spaces?

Comment: @IdanAdar notification without space

Comment: I am using 6.2 latest iFix on Mac with Oracle Java 1.6 and when the notification is received in the device, I see spaces. What is your setup?

Comment: @IdanAdar I am using worklight 6.1 and IBM JRE 1.7

Comment: For the sake of testing, please install Oracle JRE 1.6 and set Eclipse to use it. Check if there is any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62448/discussion-between-balajig-and-idan-adar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62450/discussion-between-idan-adar-and-balajig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White spaces should not be removed from the custom data, and I will open a defect for this. However,

From the documentation:

> notificationText - Optional. The string that is displayed in the
>   alert. On Windows Phone 8 the string is displayed in the application
>   tile title.
>
> payload - Optional. A JSON block that is transferred to the
>   application. On iOS and Android, the payload is transferred to the
>   application if the application is opened by the user when the
>   notification is received, or if the application is already open. On
>   Windows Phone 8, the payload is transferred to the application as a
>   raw notification only if the application is already open.

The `payload` JSON block is not meant for 'transferring' the notification text. If you will place the `notificationText` variable as the `custom` key's value, it will appear without whitespaces. But again, the payload is not where you are supposed to place the notification text to begin with.

Correct:

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
```

Incorrect:

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:notificationText});
```

In the `custom` field you could for example send some specialized "tag" that if exists, then perform a certain action in the application. Otherwise, do nothing or something else...

Comment: Can we use a url encoded text in payload of createDefaultNotification

Comment: how to pass a url encode value of payload to createDefaultNotification